# trying to find fee defaulter in FeeVoucher table and comapring it with my Admission table data..on basis of Status=Paid in FeeVoucher table

Tags: c#

i have FeeVoucher table and have RegNo attribute and month ,Class and Status and other and other table is Admission.. with student information Class,name,Reg and now i want to find Fee Defaulter student in FeeVoucher whose   Fee not paid of specific month and specific class..

i am using subquery for this...it works..but it also show other class of fee dafulter also..not showing of specific class..
here is my Sql query......

```
SELECT m.StudentName,
       m.Class,
       m.Section,
       m.Reg 
FROM   Admission m  
WHERE  m.Reg NOT IN (SELECT RegNo 
                     FROM   FeeVoucher v 
                     WHERE  Status = 'Paid' 
                     AND    Month ='Feb' 
                     AND    Class='Nursery');
```

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand your question. Can you post some data for your tables and tell us what exactly are you querying form?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move class query parameter out of the subquery.

```
select m.StudentName,m.Class,m.Section,m.Reg 
from Admission m 
where m.Reg not in(select RegNo 
                   from FeeVoucher
                   where Status='Paid' and Month='Feb')
and m.Class='Nursery'
```

Comment: You may select this answer as a solution to the question.